# jquery fileDownload: download multiple files into chunks

Tags: javascript, jquery, download

I'm using https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload to download an array of files. It seems working:

```
  for (var index = 0; index < files.length; ++index) {
    var file = files[index];
    $.fileDownload(file)
      .done(function() {
        alert("Done " + file);
      }
    )
      .fail(function() {
        alert("Fail " + file);
      }
    );
  }
```

How can I download the files in chunks of 5 files at a time?
The files are downloading, but no alert is showing for the moment. So I think maybe I have a problem here.

When trying to download 100 files, for example, I want to download 5, then other 5 etc until done for all. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you want user to click on OK to download next 5, after first 5 files are downloaded or want to download 5 files per chunk (zip?) i.e. 20 chunks?

Comment: Without clicking OK. Just to prevent 100 files downloading at the same time... but having them all downloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Download first file**

```
var firstfile = files[0]; //first file id
var downloadresult = downloadFileEx(firstfile);
```

**Then chain other files with [jquery then](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/)** and use [array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to pick the chunk

```
var begin=1; // start from second file 
var end=5;

do {

for (var index = begin; index < files.slice(begin, end).length; i++) {
 var file = files[index];
(function (index) {
      downloadresult = downloadresult.then(function() {
        return downloadFileEx(array[index]);
       });
   }(index));
 }
index++;
 }
begin = begin +5; 
end = end + 5;
}
while (end  < files.length);
```

write the file download functiom

```
function downloadFileEx(file) {
 return $.fileDownload(file)
      .done(function() {
        alert("Done " + file); // remove this 100 alerts will be blocked by browser, maintain an array of files
      }
    )
      .fail(function() {
        alert("Fail " + file);
      }
    );
}
```

Comment: I'm still working on this, the part related to that cookie fileDownload = true. Thanks for your answer. Be sure I will accept it when my solution will be done. I hope this week.

Comment: Thanks! You helped, @Anil.